# API display user details

Tags: laravel, api, model, relationship

My current API is:

[{"id":43,"title_id":1,"user_id":1,"comment":"asdasddsa","season":null,"episode":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":"2019-04-30 09:14:15"}]

I want to replace `user_id` to the user details from the user table according to id. I would like to see it this:

```
[{"id":43,"title_id":1,"users":{id:"1",username:"test",email:"example@example.com"},"comment":"asdasddsa","season":null,"episode":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":"2019-04-30 09:14:15"}]
```

**Controller**

```php
public function index($id)
{
    $test = Title::where('title_id', $id)->get();

    return $test;
}
```

**Title model**

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}

protected $table = 'title';
```

if I use `foreach()` in my controller like this:

```php
$test = Title::where('title_id', $id)->get(); 
foreach($test as $details) 
{
    return $details->user->username;
}
```

It gets the user details, but it isn't in the API. How can I get it in API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For API , it is better to [Eloquent resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources)

Example in your Title resource it will be like

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Title extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'title_id' => $this->title_id,
            'title_name' => $this->title_name,
            'user_name' => $this->user->name,
        ];
    }

    public function with($request)
    {
        return  [
            'status' => '200',
            'response' => 'Title resource',
        ];
    }
}
```

In your controller

```
 public function show(Title $title)
  {
      return new TitleResource($title);
  }
```

In 5.4 it will be like

```
public function show(Title $title)
{
    $title->user_name = $title->user->name;
    return $title->toJson();
}
```

and it should work fine

example in tinker

```
>>> $user = App\User::find(1);
=> App\User {#3161
     id: 1,
     name: "superadmin",
     email: "superadmin@example.com",
     created_at: "2018-12-13 12:09:07",
     updated_at: "2018-12-22 06:47:13",
   }
>>> $user->pk = 's';
=> "s"
>>> $user
=> App\User {#3161
     id: 1,
     name: "superadmin",
     email: "superadmin@example.com",
     created_at: "2018-12-13 12:09:07",
     updated_at: "2018-12-22 06:47:13",
     pk: "s",
   }
```

Comment: its looks like good, but App\Http\Resources\JsonResource not found

Comment: @IbrahimAldar check documentation, you don’t need to write it manually, it will be generated by artisan command, that will set correct path for your app, then you can customise the code inside.

Comment: @IbrahimAldar I have updated my answer, you can just assign your user's name as property of current `$title` and return it, it should work fine.

Comment: JsonResource added from laravel 5.6

Comment: @IbrahimAldar  use 2nd way get the model, add property convert to json and return it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$test= Title::where('title_id', $id)->get();
```

And if I understand, there is one user for one title, correct? Then you can do this to retrieve the user of a title:

```
$test->user = User::find($test->user_id);
```

And finally return the title in a json response:

```
return response()->json($test, 200);
```

Your back will send what you want, something like this:

```
[{"id":43,"title_id":1,"users":{id:"1",username:"test",email:"example@example.com"},"comment":"asdasddsa","season":null,"episode":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":"2019-04-30 09:14:15"}]
```